# put an array in two tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to put the result of an array in two tables using ng-repeat I have this array.

```
            $scope.times = [
            {"time": "20", "id": 0},
            {"time": "50", "id": 1},
            {"time": "30", "id": 2},
            {"time": "10", "id": 3},
            {"time": "85", "id": 4},
            {"time": "75", "id": 5},
            {"time": "95", "id": 6},

        ];
```

I need to put only the first 4 values in one table for example the id 0,1,2,3 in the first table and the 4,5,6 in the second table. I don't know how can I do that I use this function but don't work.

```
        $scope.verfica = function () {
        $scope.temp = [];
        $scope.temp2 = [];
        if (!$scope.times) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            $scope.temp[i] = $scope.times[i];
        }
        if ($scope.times.length > 7) {
            $scope.v = 1;
            for (var i = 3; i < $scope.times.length; i++) {
                $scope.temp2[i] = $scope.times[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

And put temp in the first table and temp2 in the second table using ng-repeat. But it doesn't work any idea or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use array.slice

```
 $scope.firstTable = $scope.times.slice(0, 3);
 $scope.secondTable = $scope.times.slice(3, 6);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app =angular.module('testApp',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.times = [
            {"time": "20", "id": 0},
            {"time": "50", "id": 1},
            {"time": "30", "id": 2},
            {"time": "10", "id": 3},
            {"time": "85", "id": 4},
            {"time": "75", "id": 5},
            {"time": "95", "id": 6},

        ];
        
    $scope.firstTable = $scope.times.slice(0, 3);
    $scope.secondTable = $scope.times.slice(3, 6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="arr in firstTable">
    <h1> first: {{arr.time}} </h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="arr in secondTable">
   <h1> second: {{arr.time}} </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the length of the array and divide it by 2 and round it for slicing.

```js
var $scope = { times: [{ time: "20", id: 0 }, { time: "50", id: 1 }, { time: "30", id: 2 }, { time: "10", id: 3 }, { time: "85", id: 4 }, { time: "75", id: 5 }, { time: "95", id: 6 }] },
    part1 = $scope.times.slice(0, Math.round($scope.times.length / 2)),
    part2 = $scope.times.slice(Math.round($scope.times.length / 2));

console.log(part1);
console.log(part2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer .splice(); This method actually rmepoves the element from the original array returning the elements at the given index.

```
   $scope.verfica = function () {
    $scope.temp = [];
    $scope.temp2 = [];
    if (!$scope.times) {
        return;
    }
   for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.times.length; i++) {
   if (i <= 3) {
     var temp = $scope.times.splice(i, 1)
     $scope.temp.push(temp);
   } 
   else if(i>3) {
    var temp = $scope.times.splice(i, 1); 
      $scope.temp2.push(temp);
         }
    }
 }
```